# IBM Notes: Where can I select the adress books chosen for autocomplete?

Tags: email, lotus-notes, contacts, address-book

When using the autocomplete-function for email addresses, Notes seems to reliably choose the most unhelpful entry from the most unrelated address book possible. About 90% of my mails go to recipients inside the company, so I could very well do with using only the main company address book. However, there seem to be multiple other address books around on the server and then there is my private address book.

I know that this problem is supposed to be partially solved by choosing "server first than local" as option in the preferences for quick addressing (please excuse if I get some terminology wrong, my Notes client is set to German language). However, there I can only choose between "deactivated", "local only" or "local first than server".

Is there another way to force notes to prefer the main company address book (server-side) over any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the option "server than local" to be visible you need to have one of two conditions met:

EITHER Your location document is set to use a local mail file (Mail Tab - Mail file location: "Local")
OR you need the following line somewhere in your notes.ini:

```
 $ServerMailAddressing=1
```

If either of these conditions is true, then there will be a new optionset below the setting "Recipient name type-ahead:", and it will be called "Mail addressing". There you will find the option "Server then local".

Beware: In all versions before 9.0.1FP10 this setting will crash your clients if the following conditions are met:

- you have feature "recent contacts" enabled
- you address a group from domino directory in a mail, the group is added to recent contacts
- you send another mail to same group --> Clientcrash...

I know, this seems unrelated, but it is proven... You need to know, if this will effect you.

Comment: Thanks, but despite adding that line to the notes.ini, I can't see a difference in behavior. 
"Server then local" is still unavailable. Is there maybe another option where I can at least choose which address books will be eligible for autocomplete?

Comment: Which version of the notes client are you using? This feature was added in a late feature pack for 9.0.1. And did you add an empty line AFTER the new entry in the notes.ini? The last line in notes.ini is never read, if you have no empty line at the end it will not work...

Comment: Oh, wow... I'd never have figured out that you had to leave an empty line at the end 
Now it works, thanks a lot!